# Updating children in one-to-many relationship using Entity Framework with repository and unit-of-work patterns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, one-to-many

I am working on a project to migrate an existing WPF application to the web. The database is already here. The update has been done using stored procedures in the existing project.

I have a class like this

```
class Person
{
    int ID;
    string Name;
    string Address;

    virtual IList<Contact> Contacts;
}

class Contact
{
    int ID;
    int PersonID;
    virtual Person Person;
    string Carrier;
    string ContactNumber;
}
```

I need to be able to modify `ContactNumber` of `Contact` through `PersonRepository`.

The repository is something like

```
IRepository<Person> _personRepository;
```

Adding a new person can be done using

```
_personRepsitory.Add(person)
_unitOfWork.commit()
```

but update cannot be done using

```
_personRepository.Update(person)
_unitOfWork.commit()
```

Entity Framework throws an error saying children are not nullable and should be deleted before updating. But I have been told to perform update without deleting children using Entity Framework. Can this update be done using without deleting the existing children? If so, how? If not, what are other options?

Comment: You should not call `Update` at all. Tracked entities are automatically updated by EF.

Comment: The Update method actually does nothing. It is there just for code consistency.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on what the `PersonRepository.Update()` method does. A unit of work pattern is intended to wrap the scope of a DbContext that the repository will utilize. These types of issues typically materialize when entities, in your case person and their related contacts, are brought in from outside the scope of the Unit of Work / DbContext.

With WPF / Windows applications the DbContext scope is typically more long-lived where entities are loaded based on one action like a page loading, and while that page is visible, that DbContext instance is kept alive so further events can be actioned against the Context using the loaded entities.  With web applications this has to consider things a little differently.

DbContexts should have a short life, and in a web application that is typically linked to the life of the individual request, or shorter. (It should never be longer) The default behaviour that many examples follow would be that when a page is loaded, the DbContext instance is queried, then the entities are fed to the view to serve as the model. Then when a form is submitted or an Ajax call is made, that model is passed back to the controller action. The issue here is that while it looks similar to the WPF code in that the actions receive what looks like an EF Entity, what they are actually getting is a deserialized POCO, not a tracked entity. The DbContext for that request knows nothing about that object instance. This means that details like change tracking are completely missing and for all intensive purpose, that "entity" and any related details are treated as new data and otherwise cannot be trusted to represent the actual data state. (I.e. not guaranteed to be complete if data was not eager loaded etc.)

So the important factors to consider with web applications when doing an update:
What gets passed in is not a tracked entity, so you cannot treat it like one. One option is to attach it to the DbContext, and set its entity state to `Modified`. I do not recommend using this approach for three reasons.

1. This "trusts" that the data passed in hasn't been tampered with. Web debugging tools allow malicious manipulation of data passed in Ajax or form posts.
2. Where data has possible related data, these related entities must also all be attached or you end up with issues like exceptions, duplicate data, etc.
3. Even when attaching entities you must have checks for whether the DbContext might already be tracking an instance, otherwise you get situational exceptions.

That last point is a nasty one that can lead to errors that can be deceptively hard to reproduce. Say you update a customer that has one or more orders and each order references one or more products. When you pass these orders to a method if two orders reference the same "Product" the deserialized objects would  contain two distinct references to "Product A". Attaching "Product A" as part of the first order would succeed, but now that the DbContext is tracking that instance, attaching the "Product A" from the second order would fail. You *must* always check for existing tracked references and replace those references if found. The error doesn't occur if there are no duplicate references or the DbContext isn't otherwise tracking a reference. (A situational runtime error)

To handle updates, if you must pass entities then you have to treat those entities as you would a completely different object. (DTO or ViewModel) This means to be safe, load the current data state and copy the relevant values from the passed in data into the tracked instance and save changes. This ensures:

1. You take control of what data can, and should not be overwritten.
2. You load the complete applicable data state and only update what you expect, there are no surprises based on what data does, or does not come back. (no duplicate data risk for detached entities)
3. There are no surprises around existing tracked entities.

The added benefit over even simple cases where there are no related entities and you're tempted to `Attach()` and set state to `Modified` or call `Update()` is that when copying values across and leveraging EF's change tracking, it will only generate and run an Update statement if a value actually changes, and only for the values that actually change. `Update()` or `EntityState.Modified` will result **always** in an update statement that updates **all** columns whether they changed or not. This can have an undesirable effect/cost on using things like auditing checks.

So what a typical Update method should look like, at a very basic level:

```
public Person Update(Person person)
{
    if (person == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("person");
    var existingPerson = _context.Persons
        .Include(x => x.Contacts)
        .Single(x => x.PersonId == person.PersonId);

    existingPerson.Name = person.Name;
    // only update fields expected to be changed.

    foreach(var contact in person.Contacts)
    {
        var existingContact = existingPerson.Contacts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ContactId == contact.ContactId);
        // handle whether a contact exists or not, insert a new contact or update, etc.
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return existingPerson;
}
```

Better still, since this can make it difficult to work out when Contacts might be edited, added, or removed, it can help to organize actions to be more granular. For example:

```
AddContact(personId, contact);
UpdateContact(personId, contact);
RemoveContact(personId, contactId);
```

These actions can load the Person and related contacts data without having the overhead of repeatedly sending the entire Person details, and perform specific actions with the details provided.

No messing around with attaching the untracked instances, and generally safe from unexpected tampering. Ideally the methods would deal strictly with view models rather than passing in/returning entities.